# Product space is completed with metric $d(x,y):=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\min\{2^{-i},d_i(x_i,y_i)\}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

We have the completed metric spaces $((S_i,d_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $S:=\Pi_{i\in\mathbb{N}}S_i$ with the metric $d(x,y):=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\min\{2^{-i},d_i(x_i,y_i)\}.$ How to show, that $(S,d)$ is also completed.
Attempt: I want to show, that if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy-Sequence in $S$, then $(x_{n_{i}})$ is a Cauchy-Sequence in $S_i, \ i\in\mathbb{N}.$ Then we would know, that $(x_{n_{i}})$ converges and I can set the limit $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Each term in the infinite sum is less than or equal to the infinite  sum. That is all you need to prove that the i-th coordinates form a Cauchy sequence for each i.

Comment: I got stuck with the limit $x$. For all $i\in\mathbb{N}, \epsilon> 0$ it exists $N_i>0$ with $d(x_{n_{i}},x_i)<\epsilon.$ But if I consider $d(x_n,x)$, I have to look at $\sup N_i$. But what, if it's infinite?